# Is there an easier way to find the count of a variable using multiple criterias? R

Tags: r

I have a CSV file with two columns like this:

### **education**   -----  marital

primary       ------------------married
secondary  --------------single
secondary  --------------divorced
tertiary  -------------------married
primary   ------------------single
tertiary -------------------divorced

and so on. The columns are in the 3rd and 4th position in the dataset. I wanted to find the number of people who had a tertiary education and are also married. I did this in two ways. First,

```
with(bank.df, table(education, marital))
```

and then just noted the amount that was displayed in the table. Then I used

```
sum((bank.df[4]== "married" & bank.df[3]== "tertiary"))
```

which gave me just the number. Are there simpler/alternative ways I can achieve the same thing?

Comment: What is the issue with the code you tried.  Other option include `bank.df %>% count(education, marital)` or `bank.df %>% filter(education == 'tertiary', marital == 'married')` - returns the subset of rows

Comment: There weren't any issues with either. They both got me the correct result. I just felt how I achieved it wasn't as straight forward as it should be.

Comment: `sum` seems to be good.  With `table` or `count` you are counting all the combinations.  In your case, it seems that you want only a specific combination

Comment: `xtabs( ~ education + marital, subset(bank.df, education == "tertiary" & marital == "married"))`.

Answer (score 0):

The table gives you all of the combinations and you can easily select the cell you need, but if you are going to do lots of different combinations of columns/values, you can make a simple function to give you the count for any combination:

```
getcount <- function(x, col1, val1, col2, val2) {
    sum((bank.df[, col1] == val1 & bank.df[, col2] == val2))
}
getcount(bank.df, "marital", "married", "education", "tertiary")
# [1] 1
```